# Select multiple input fields javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have made a HTML form with several input fields like these:

```
            <tr>
                <td>inputfield1</td>
                <td><input type="number" class="bestelformulier" name="inputfield1" onkeyup="validateForm()" min="1" max="999"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>inputfield2</td>
                <td><input type="number" class="bestelformulier" name="inputfield2" min="1" max="999"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>inputfield3</td>
                <td><input type="number" class="bestelformulier" name="inputfield3" min="1" max="999"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>inputfield4</td>
                <td><input type="number" class="bestelformulier" name="inputfield4" min="1" max="999"></td>
            </tr>
```

As you can see my input field 1 has an onkeyup event called 'validateForm()' which does the following:

```
function validateForm(){
        if(document.forms['form'].inputfield1.value == "")
        {
            document.forms[0].submit.disabled=true;
        }
        else {  
            document.forms[0].submit.disabled=false;
        }
    }
```

It disables the button if nothing is filled in inputfield1 but enables it if there is something in there.

This works just as it should.

But as you can see i have several inputfields which all need a function like that.

The button needs to be disabled when 0 out of 11 fields are filled but needs to be enabled if even 1 of them is filled (doesn't matter which one)

How do I make it so that if 1 of those 11 fields are filled the button will enable?

All help is grealy appreciated!

Comment: You will have to either store the state of all the other inputs and check each one every time you call `validateForm`. Otherwise, your best bet is to move the `validateForm` call to the form "onsubmit" event, and check all the fields then.

Comment: And what should i place in the validateform itself? since it will still only check input field1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this and add it to the keyup off all the input fields

```
function validateForm()
{

    var allEmpty = (document.forms['form'].inputfield1.value == "" &&
                    document.forms['form'].inputfield2.value == "" &&
                    document.forms['form'].inputfield3.value == "" &&
                    document.forms['form'].inputfield4.value == "");

    if(allEmpty) // if all are empty disable the button, else enable it.
    {
        document.forms[0].submit.disabled=true;
    }
    else {  
        document.forms[0].submit.disabled=false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Only problem with this is scaling, if he suddenly needs to add 10 more fields, or all the fields needed a name change, it could become annoying to maintain. Good solution overall :)

Comment: You're able to circumvent the min/max this way. You can also proceed with one of the inputs actually being empty

Comment: Actually sorry I misread the question, that is allowed. However you can still circumvent the min/max check

Comment: @danrichardson what do you mean exactly?

Comment: checking for `value == ""` means that a value of "bob" would be valid, which it isn't, as the value (based on your code) needs to be a number between 1 and 999.

Answer (score 0):

For achieving this you need to pass the Id of the element to the function.

Make the function call like this

```
  onkeyup="validateForm('inputfield1')";
```

apply this for all input fields and update function like below

Try this

```
function validateForm(eleId){
    var value = document.getElementById(eleId).value;
    if(value == "")
    {
        document.forms[0].submit.disabled=true;
    }
    else {  
        document.forms[0].submit.disabled=false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd doubt that would work as the `eleId` passed would be a string and not an element under `document.forms[]`

Comment: I can't really tell if this one works aswell or not, but i used thetop answer and that one works for sure, thanks for the effort though!

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('bestelformulier'); //you can use another class if you want.. as 'required'
var cansubmit = false;
for (i=0; i<input.length; i++)
    if(input[i].value.trim() != "")
        cansubmit = true;

document.forms[0].submit.disabled = cansubmit;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: sorry about  the brace in the end of "for" ... you can remove that.. I will edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript needs to check the validity of the value also (between 1 and 999). This will also check the form on submit, not just rely on the fields being edited. 
Full code.

```
<form name="form" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <tr>
            <td>inputfield1</td>
            <td><input type="text" class="bestelformulier" name="inputfield1" onkeyup="validateForm()" min="1" max="999"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>inputfield2</td>
            <td><input type="number" class="bestelformulier" name="inputfield2" onkeyup="validateForm()" min="1" max="999"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>inputfield3</td>
            <td><input type="number" class="bestelformulier" name="inputfield3" onkeyup="validateForm()" min="1" max="999"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>inputfield4</td>
            <td><input type="number" class="bestelformulier" name="inputfield4" onkeyup="validateForm()" min="1" max="999"></td>
        </tr>
        <input type="submit" disabled name="submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm() {    
        var isValid = false;
        if (document.forms[0].inputfield1.value > 0 && document.forms[0].inputfield1.value < 1000) {
            isValid = true;
        }
        if (document.forms[0].inputfield2.value > 0 && document.forms[0].inputfield2.value < 1000) {
            isValid = true;
        }
        if (document.forms[0].inputfield3.value > 0 && document.forms[0].inputfield3.value < 1000) {
            isValid = true;
        }
        if (document.forms[0].inputfield4.value > 0 && document.forms[0].inputfield4.value < 1000) {
            isValid = true;
        }
        if (!isValid) {
            document.forms[0].submit.disabled = true;
        } else {
            document.forms[0].submit.disabled = false;
        }
        return isValid;
    }
</script>
```